# Why is there a package for centernot?

Tags: packages, relation-symbols

I was very surprised when I noticed that there was a package on CTAN for the centernot command.
Specifically, what is the difference between `\@centernot` and `\c@ncel` (which is part of Plain TeX)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\c@ncel` (used in the default `\notin`) is

```
\def\c@ncel#1#2{\m@th\ooalign{$\hfil#1\mkern1mu/\hfil$\crcr$#1#2$}}
```

Note this doesn't take care of `\mathrel` spacing or subscript size, so is used wrapped such as

```
\DeclareRobustCommand
  \notin{\mathrel{\m@th\mathpalette\c@ncel\in}}
```

Conversely `\@centerdot` uses a different centering mechanism and applies `\mathrel`

```
\newcommand*{\centernot}{%
  \mathpalette\@centernot
}
\def\@centernot#1#2{%
  \mathrel{%
    \rlap{%
      \settowidth\dimen@{$\m@th#1{#2}$}%
      \kern.5\dimen@
      \settowidth\dimen@{$\m@th#1=$}%
      \kern-.5\dimen@
      $\m@th#1\not$%
    }%
    {#2}%
  }%
}
```

it also uses `\not` rather than `/` for the /.

So like many other packages they are different implementations with similar use cases.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{centernot}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand\cnot[1]{\mathrel{\m@th\mathpalette\c@ncel#1}}
\begin{document}


$ A \centernot\subset B $

$ A \cnot\subset B $


$ A \centernot\rightarrow B $

$ A \cnot\rightarrow B $
\end{document}
```